# 'to_string' unknown override specifier

Tags: c++, string, class, header, overriding

For an assignment I am supposed to use the following class in a header file `'date.h'` However when I attempted to compile my program I got an error stating:

> 'to_string': unknown override specifier.

What is wrong with the following code? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class Date
{
private:
    int m_day, m_month, m_year;
public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y)
    {    
        m_day = d; m_month = m; m_year = y;
    }

    int getDay() const { return m_day; }
    int getMonth() const { return m_month; }
    int getYear() const { return m_year; }
    string to_string() const
    {
        stringstream s;
        s << getMonth() << "/" << getDay() << "/" << getYear();
        return s.str();
    }
};
#endif
```

Comment: This code compiles fine for me (gcc 4.9). Perhaps its something in your .cpp file. `to_string` is a c++11 standard function, and I notice you're not using scope resolution, so perhaps there is compiler confusion there. I would avoid `using namespace std` and instead use `std::string` etc. What compiler are you using? Can we see the function calling `to_string`?

Answer (score 2):

it may be because string is part of the standard library. You should do this instead:

```
std::string to_string() const {

}
```

Comment: Or add `using namespace std;` in the top of the file